# grab xml child of child element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have successfully accessed itemId, galleryURL, title, viewItemURL value under item collections but problem is i need to access another value which is not directly under item collections it just inside another child. Please have a look on this picture of XML [image: picture of XML] to get better idea. Please advice me how can i access listingInfo->watchCount

```
public ActionResult Search(string OperationName, string calltype, string page, string keywords, string type, string location, string condition, string min, string max, string negative, string minFeedback, string maxFeedback, string drange, string categoryId)
{
    string AppId = "demo-key"; //api configs
    string BaseUrl = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME="; //base url api end point

    if (calltype == "categoryClick")
    {
        string Url = BaseUrl + OperationName + "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=" + AppId + "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&categoryId=" + categoryId + "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=2&paginationInput.pageNumber=" + page + "";

        var items = new List<EbayDataViewModel>();

        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Url);

        // Since i am only interested in <item> collections within <searchResult>
        var searchResultItems = xdoc.Descendants()
            .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "item");

        foreach (var sri in searchResultItems)
        {
            // Get all child xml elements
            var childElements = sri.Elements();

            var itemId = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "itemId");
            var imageurl = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "galleryURL");
            var title = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "title");
            var url = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "viewItemURL");
           // var numberofwatch = childElements.Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "listinginfo"); this is one step inside of another element

            //add items from xml data to EbayDataViewModel object
            items.Add(new EbayDataViewModel
            {
                ItemId = itemId == null ? String.Empty : itemId.Value,
                EbayImageUrl = imageurl == null ? String.Empty : imageurl.Value,
                EbayTitle = title == null ? String.Empty : title.Value,
                EbayUrl = url == null ? String.Empty : url.Value,
                //NumberOfWatch = numberofwatch == null ? String.Empty : numberofwatch.Value,
            });
        }
        var e = Json(items);
        return Json(items);

    }else{

    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPathSelectElement (see [MSDN XPathSelectElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
string str =
@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<sri>
    <item><listingInfo><watchCount>1</watchCount></listingInfo></item>
    <item><listingInfo><watchCount>2</watchCount></listingInfo></item>
</sri>";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
var searchResultItems = xdoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "item");
foreach (var item in searchResultItems)
{
    var wc = item.XPathSelectElement("listingInfo/watchCount");
    Console.WriteLine(wc.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code solves your problem i think

> var nofwatch = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName ==
>   "listingInfo").Elements().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName ==
>   "watchCount");

```
foreach (var sri in searchResultItems)
                {
                    // Get all child xml elements
                    var childElements = sri.Elements();

                    var itemId = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "itemId");
                    var imageurl = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "galleryURL");
                    var title = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "title");
                    var url = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "viewItemURL");
                    var nofwatch = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "listingInfo").Elements().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "watchCount");

                    //add items from xml data to EbayDataViewModel object
                    items.Add(new EbayDataViewModel
                    {
                        ItemId = itemId == null ? String.Empty : itemId.Value,
                        EbayImageUrl = imageurl == null ? String.Empty : imageurl.Value,
                        EbayTitle = title == null ? String.Empty : title.Value,
                        EbayUrl = url == null ? String.Empty : url.Value,
                        NumberOfWatch = nofwatch == null ? String.Empty : nofwatch.Value,
                    });
                }
```